# Formatting issue when copy paste data from html to excel

Tags: css, html, excel, jquery-datatables-editor

I have a table which i generated from Php, and i am using datatable.js to add some options and pagination to the data.

When I copy and paste the data to excel by doing a ctrl + a and ctrl + c then ctrl + v ( windows )

a ) In chrome I get a the dropdown in excel like this (http://prntscr.com/8r4x71) however the table is not broken .

b ) in firefox I do not get the annoying drop down, however the table last row is broken like this (http://prntscr.com/8r4vqy)

I have created a simple fiddle to represent the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/63g6e655/2/

Below is the html, the js and the css are in the fiddle

```
<div id="content" class="well well-lg">

    <div id="mainContent">


        <table id="report_gen_user" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="left">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>item</th>
                    <th>Features </th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total(USD)</th>
                    <th>Reference</th>
                    <th>Transaction ID</th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>generated by </th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>


                                    <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;2009-10-03</td>
                                <td>4000</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td> test</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>b</td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;2009-10-03</td>
                                <td>2000</td>
                                <td>Ilorum ipsum</td>
                                <td> lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>b</td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;2009-10-03</td>
                                <td>4000</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td> lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>bf</td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;2009-10-03</td>
                                <td>2000</td>
                                <td>aaa</td>
                                <td> aaa</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>asdadasd</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;asdad</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;asdasd</td>
                                <td>b</td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;2009-10-03</td>
                                <td>2000</td>
                                <td>asdadE</td>
                                <td> lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;2009-10-03</td>
                                <td>2000</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td> test</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>bt</td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;2009-10-03</td>
                                <td>2000</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td> lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>bfg</td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;2009-10-03</td>
                                <td>2000</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td> lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;lorum ipsum</td>
                                <td>bfsg</td>
                            </tr>



            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Totals:</th>
                    <th >&nbsp;</th>
                    <th class="unselect" >&nbsp;</th>
                    <th >&nbsp;</th>
                    <th >&nbsp;</th>
                    <th >&nbsp;</th>
                    <th >&nbsp;</th>
                    <th >&nbsp;</th>
                    <th >&nbsp;</th>
                    <th >&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated to solve the above 2 issues.

Comment: You could try to export this to google calc and then try to copy | pasate. It usually works in my case when i have problem with text. I hope it can help you.

Comment: hi Ganga, thank you for the input, however in my case i developed this system for use with some co workers, its quite hectic to tell them to do these procedures, specially when they has to send many invoices to clients per day. I was wondering if there could be a fix in the html so that , 1; in google when i copy paste it to excel it does not bring the dropdown and 2nd in firefox when i copy paste it brings the last row correctly.